# Firebase v9 orderBy error: failed to fetch data TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'startAt')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to Firebase v9 and I cannot seem to make the `orderBy` work, but when I tried in the Firebase console, I can see the results if I were to use the `orderBy`

[image]

error:

> Failed to fetch data TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined
> (reading 'startAt')

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const retrieve = async () => {
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "orders"));
    const q = query(querySnapshot, orderBy("orderCreatedAt"));
    console.log(q, "q");
    const arr = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      arr.push({
        ...doc.data(),
        id: doc.id,
      });
    });
    if (isMounted) {
      setOrders(arr);
    }
  };
}, []);
```

in the firebase console:

[image]

Comment: Just an FYI, you're missing a call to `retrieve()` in your effect hook

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [query()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_#query) functions accepts a [Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.query.md#query_class) instance for the first parameter. This can be provided by the [CollectionReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.collectionreference.md#collectionreference_class) returned by `collection()`.

Your issue is that you are passing it the result of `getDocs()` which resolves with a [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.querysnapshot.md#querysnapshot_class).

I think you need something like this

```js
const ordersRef = collection(db, "orders");
const q = query(ordersRef, orderBy("orderCreatedAt");
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
```

See also

- [Perform simple and compound queries in Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries)
- [Order and limit data with Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data)

---

I would highly recommend using [typescript](/questions/tagged/typescript) to avoid these sorts of issues. It would have immediately told you that your original `querySnapshot` wasn't the right type for use in `query()`.